# Как перебрать два массива и сравнить их по условию?

Tags: javascript, массивы, foreach

есть код

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-th="ETFdb Pro"]').forEach(node =>       console.log(node.innerText));
document.querySelectorAll('[data-th="Symbol"]').forEach(tiker => console.log(node.innerText));
```

и мне нужно сделать следующее:
если значение в первом массиве соответсвуют A+ или B+ то мы выводим то мы выходим тиккер компании по счету такой же как и значение[image: введите сюда описание изображения]